# Mobile Device detection using asp.net and C#

Tags: mobile, detection

I have to detect mobile browser and if detect as mobile browser then I have to show some content on the web page.

I am using `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` but it fails for iPhone like handsets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if that can help you but, few months ago i used driveInfo to detect USB device

maybe that can work for detect your iPhone
try to take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.isready.aspx

And for the event you can try this:

```
static ManagementEventWatcher w = null;

private static void USBHandler(){ 

WqlEventQuery q; 
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2"); 
scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true; 
  q = new WqlEventQuery(); 
  q.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent"; 
  q.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3); 
  q.Condition = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'"; 
  w = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q); 
  w.EventArrived += USBInserted; 
  w.Start(); 
}
private static void USBInserted(object sender, EventArgs e){

System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("USB inserted");
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply... but i have to use in web application ... i have another solution to check User Agent. but i am checking for every phone like Iphone Ipod, HTC, Android. as they have their own diffrent User Agent.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://51degrees.mobi/ You can download their nuget package into your project it works well to detect mobile devices